# Is it possible to replace all the contents of the first row of an HTML table without assigning an ID to each <td> element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html table consisting table headers and a first row as shown below:

```
<html>
<table>
<thead>
<th>name</th>
<th>email</th>
</head>
<tr>
<td>Kipchoge</td>
<td>k@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" onClick="fn()"/>
</html>
```

How can I change all the contents of the first row with my custom text when I click the button?
I have tried assigning my new text directly to `document.getElementByTagName("tr")[1].innerHTML` with no success as shown in the code below:

```js
function fn(){
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var customtext = "";
d[1].innerHTML = customtext;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
<th>name</th>
<th>email</th>
</head>
<tr>
<td>Kipchoge</td>
<td>k@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" onClick="fn()"/>
```

I know that what I have done in the above code is trying to assign a new value to an existing `innerHTML` value which can be easily achieved when you use `getElementById`, but my idea is to change all the values of the first row once without assigning an id to each `<td></td>`.
Is there an alternative approach? Or what should I do to my approach in order to solve such a problem?

I tried changing existing `innerHTML` with new text as shown below:

```
d[1].innerHTML = customtext;
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getElementsByTagName` returns a [live HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)  which is an array-like-object of elements. In your code you are trying to add text inside a table row node. Table row - or `tr` - is only allowed to have `td` elements inside it. In the following example, I am using `innerHTML` to set HTML that represents the that contains the `td` with the text inside them.

```js
function fn(){
  var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
  tr.innerHTML = `<td>Text 1</td><td>Text 2</td>`;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Kipchoge</td>
    <td>k@gmail.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" onClick="fn()"/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the more powerful [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to select elements from the DOM by using CSS Selectors. In your case you can select the first row with `tbody tr:first-of-type`.

```js
const firstTableRow = document.querySelector('tbody tr:first-of-type');

firstTableRow.cells[0].textContent = 'Foo';
firstTableRow.cells[1].textContent = 'foo@bar.com';
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Kipchoge</td>
      <td>k@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Kipchoge</td>
      <td>k@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the table heads in this way

```
<html>
<table>
<thead>
<th>name</th>
<th>email</th>
</head>
<tr>
<td>Kipchoge</td>
<td>k@gmail.com</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="btn" onClick="fn()"/>
</html>


// you can target thead and get all ths that are present inside it

const head = document.getElementById("thead-id") /* or */ document.querySelector('thead')
// if you don't want all th in thead only the ones in first row of the thead
//(incase you have more than one rows in thead)
const row = document.querySelector("thead tr:first-of-type") /* or */ document.querySelector("#thead-id tr:first-of-type")

const thList = head.querySelectorAll("th");
// or 
const thList = row.querySelectorAll("th");
// Now th list acts like a list or an array where you can target items using index or run a forEach loop
thList.forEach((th) => {
th.innerText = "customText"
})
```